# How to start for loop from 1

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

```java
int keyCardNum = 10;
for(int x = 0; x<= keyCardNum; x++) {
        System.out.println(x);
}
```

It prints the following:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Online I read that for loops start from 0. It that true and how can I remove the 0 and start from 1 to 10.

Comment: See that `int x = 0` part in the loop? Now take some time to think about it for a while...

Comment: For loops don't "start from 0". They start from where the programmer tells them to start. Just change `x` to `1` and `keyCardNum` to `11`, or print `x + 1` instead of `x`. Personally, I prefer the latter method.

Comment: `for(int x = 1; x<= keyCardNum; x++)`

Answer (score 4):

```java
for(int x = 0; x <= keyCardNum; x++)
```

Defines three properties of the [`for` loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html):

1. `int x = 0`: one or more loop variables and their initial value. Executed once when the loop starts. Usually, this variable is called `i`.
2. `x <= keyCardNum`: the loop condition. Executed once per iteration. The loop terminates when this condition evaluates false. (the loop never runs if the condition evaluates to false immediately). Usually this is a less-than (`<`) expression. `i=0;i<10;++i` will loop 10 times, `i=0;i<=10;++i` will loop 11 times.
3. `x++`: the incrementor. Executed once per iteration. Here you define what happens after each loop iteration. Usually, you increment the loop counter variable, but you could do anything here.

The loop body is executed as many times as the loop condition evaluates to true. If you are interested in the nitty-gritty details, the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1) has them.

If you want a loop to start at `1`, you have to initialize the loop variable with `1`. Or, you "normalize" your loop variable when using them in an expression, e.g. `x + 1` to produce a value offset by 1 (i.e. 1-11 in your example).